# Infinite sum and the index of summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given: $\bar{V}_t = \sum\limits_{s=t}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s-t} \cdot \Pi_s \right]$

Goal: Rewrite to $\bar{V}_0 = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^t \cdot \Pi_t \right]$

My attempt: $\sum\limits_{s=t}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s-t} \cdot \Pi_s \right] = \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{(s+t)-t} \cdot \Pi_{s + t} \right] = \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s} \cdot \Pi_{s + t} \right]$ (index shift), or, equivalently: $\sum\limits_{s=t}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s-t} \cdot \Pi_s \right] = \sum\limits_{\tilde{t}=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{(\tilde{t}+t)-t} \cdot \Pi_{\tilde{t}+t} \right] = \sum\limits_{\tilde{t}=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{\tilde{t}} \cdot \Pi_{\tilde{t}+t} \right]$ (index change), but this does not lead to the required result (yet).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You have
$$\bar{V}_t = \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s} \cdot \Pi_{s + t} \right]$$
Now substitute $t=0$ on both sides:
$$\bar{V}_0 = \sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{s} \cdot \Pi_s \right]$$
Now change $s$ to $t$:
$$\bar{V}_0 = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+R}\right)^{t} \cdot \Pi_t \right]$$